# What is the name of this function similar to convolution?

Tags: fourier-analysis, laplace-transform, convolution

The functions seems to be very near convolution function, but the only difference is that you integrate by $du$ in convolution, in contrast to $ds$ in this example:

$g(t,u) 
\overset{\underset{\mathrm{def}}{}}{=} 
\int_{t-u/2}^{t+u/2} f(s+\frac{u}{2}) \overline{ f(s - \frac{u}{2}) } ds$

**What is the name of this function which does some windowing?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks basically like an autocorrelation (continuous cross-correlation) at lag $u$ to me. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation).

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing that comes to mind is a special case of a [Wigner distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_distribution_function#Mathematical_definition) for a signal of finite support.